# How can I beat all the 4 enemies in "Golden Horde" by Serjik Waters in Golden Horde?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I have been playing this game, where I had beaten 1/4 enemies in the game. But after that an orange enemy is very difficult to defeat and the other 2 are very strong, so when I concentrate on 1 the others build quickly. What/s the best strategy to defeat all the enemies in the game?

Comment: Please rephrase that question to be something like: How can I beat "The Golden Horde" most effectively? Since now, I would just say: yes or no + some random tip that seemed to work

Comment: Turtle and defend till you have a large army. Take out each opponent one by one. It's best if you take out the most active enemies early which would give you some time to build and expand. This is just a general tip since I haven't played AOE 2 in a long time.

Comment: The strategy I always used while playing Age of Empires II is to first focus on building up resources and personal defenses. I didn't try attacking at first. The enemies build up their bases, but they don't extend really far. they stop after having a specific amount of buildings. You can expand s you like after being able to fend them off. While they are being put down by your castles, towers, and defense soldiers, you can build up an attacking force for the offense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Golden Horde" by Serjik Waters for AOEII.

Perhaps you mean AOEIII.
In that case there is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlFyWEGrAvc) which shows how to beat them.

Comment: Link-only answers can become useless if the link dies. Please include a (short) summary of the link contents in the answer itself.

Comment: The answer was actually the first line. I think it would be useless to put a summary here for a wrong question, although I completely agree on your statement.